# Cordova whitelist not doing what its supposed to do?

Tags: javascript, cordova, azure, ionic-framework

I have `$<access origin="*" />` in my xml file and

```
$<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *http://for3s.azurewebsites.net http://localhost:1337 http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com">
```

in my `index.html` file. I have tried other examples of this meta tag, but it's always the same error message:

> "Refused to load the script 'http://for3s.azurewebsites.net/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5&connectionData=%5B%5D&callback=jQuery16405339114761445671_1448321915826&_=1448321923021' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *http://for3s.azurewebsites.net http://localhost:1337 http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com".`

Answer (score 0):

Take out the * from the *http://for3s.azurewebsites.net, which is probably causing your false negative.

Comment: Problem was likely the * with no space before the http://... you want either * (everything) or a list of URLs, rather than a mix and match of both.